# Loss of Accuracy when adding a second hidden layer on MNIST dataset using Back propagation

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am attempting to add a second hidden layer to a working neural network with a hand calculated back propagation (instead of tensorflow's built in version).

Instead of one layer of ReLU and one layer of softmax, I'm attempting to add in a second layer. The result is a complete loss of accuracy, from 92.3% to 8.5% with no improvements.

At first I thought my error was in my back propagation calculation, but I double checked in and also ran it by commenting out what I had written, and utilizing

step1 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost)

in place of my backpropagation section listed below. This also resulted in a low accuracy. To further confuse me, if I use AdamOptimizer(0.0001) in place of Gradient Descent, the code does improve the overall results as expected, 97% accuracy.

Why am I losing accuracy here?

## Back Propagation

```
d_z_3 = tf.multiply(cost, sigmaprime(z_3)) #OK?
d_b_3 = d_z_3
d_w_3 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_2), d_z_3)
d_a_2= tf.matmul(d_z_3, tf.transpose(w_3))
d_z_2 = tf.multiply(d_a_2, d_relu(z_2))#change
d_b_2 = d_z_2
d_w_2 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_1), d_z_2)
d_a_1 = tf.matmul(d_z_2, tf.transpose(w_2))
d_z_1 = tf.multiply(d_a_1, d_relu(z_1)) #change
d_b_1 = d_z_1
d_w_1 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_0), d_z_1)
eta = tf.constant(0.5)

step1 = [
    tf.assign(w_1,
            tf.subtract(w_1, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_1)))
  , tf.assign(b_1,
            tf.subtract(b_1, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_1, axis=[0]))))
  , tf.assign(w_2,
            tf.subtract(w_2, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_2)))
  , tf.assign(b_2,
            tf.subtract(b_2, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_2, axis=[0]))))
  , tf.assign(w_3,
            tf.subtract(w_3, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_3)))
  , tf.assign(b_3,
            tf.subtract(b_3, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_3, axis=[0]))))
]
```

## Entire Code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
a_0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

middle = 100

#randomize the weights
w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, middle] , stddev=0.01))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, middle]))
w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([middle, middle] , stddev=0.01))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, middle]))
w_3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([middle, 10] , stddev=0.01))
b_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 10] ))

#forward propagation (with  relu 2x, softmax)
z_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_0, w_1), b_1)
a_1 = tf.nn.relu(z_1)
z_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_1, w_2), b_2)
a_2 = tf.nn.relu(z_2)
z_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_2, w_3), b_3)
a_3 = tf.nn.softmax(z_3) 
diff = tf.subtract(a_3, y)
cost = tf.multiply(diff, diff)

#backpropagation
d_z_3 = tf.multiply(cost, sigmaprime(z_3)) #OK?
d_b_3 = d_z_3
d_w_3 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_2), d_z_3)
d_a_2= tf.matmul(d_z_3, tf.transpose(w_3))
d_z_2 = tf.multiply(d_a_2, d_relu(z_2))#change
d_b_2 = d_z_2
d_w_2 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_1), d_z_2)
d_a_1 = tf.matmul(d_z_2, tf.transpose(w_2))
d_z_1 = tf.multiply(d_a_1, d_relu(z_1)) #change
d_b_1 = d_z_1
d_w_1 = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(a_0), d_z_1)
eta = tf.constant(0.5)

step1 = [
    tf.assign(w_1,
            tf.subtract(w_1, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_1)))
  , tf.assign(b_1,
            tf.subtract(b_1, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_1, axis=[0]))))
  , tf.assign(w_2,
            tf.subtract(w_2, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_2)))
  , tf.assign(b_2,
            tf.subtract(b_2, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_2, axis=[0]))))
  , tf.assign(w_3,
            tf.subtract(w_3, tf.multiply(eta, d_w_3)))
  , tf.assign(b_3,
            tf.subtract(b_3, tf.multiply(eta,
                               tf.reduce_mean(d_b_3, axis=[0]))))
]

#end backpropagation section

acct_mat = tf.equal(tf.argmax(a_3, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
acct_res = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(acct_mat, tf.float32))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(10000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    sess.run(step1, feed_dict = {a_0: batch_xs, y : batch_ys})
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        res = sess.run(acct_res, feed_dict =
                       {a_0: mnist.test.images[:1000],
                        y : mnist.test.labels[:1000]})
        print(res/1000)
```

Comment: can you try to decrease the learning rate in the GradientDescentOptimizer? when you add more weights, you should decrease the learning rate. try 0.0001 like you did in Adam.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've attempted that and it 'improves' the results shortly but then reverts to a lack of improvement, this time holding at 12.6%. 

I set step1 as:

step1 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.000001).minimize(cost)

Comment: Update it worked for 0.01 for the built in optimizerThank you @yahia-Zakaria